# Using LinqKit to Apply a Query to a Single Complex Property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linqpad, linqkit

**EDIT:** I managed to reduce my code to the least-common-denominator with the assistance of LinqPad.

I have a method that returns a complex LinqKit predicate. The desired result is to be able to reuse this method whenever I need to perform this query. It works fine in a `Where` clause against an `IQueryable` collection of these entities, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use this predicate when I have this entity as a single property of an object, and want to use predicates to query the other properties of that entity.

I'll give you a simplified example of what I mean.

```
// Note: .Includes removed for brevity's sake.
var task = Tasks.First(t => t.QaConfigTaskId == 2);

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Task>();

// Ensure that the task's own properties match.
predicate = predicate.And(t => t.TaskType == task.TaskType &&
      t.Description == task.Description &&
      t.PreTreatment == task.PreTreatment &&
      t.Treatment == task.Treatment);

var structureAnalysis = task.StructureAnalysis;
var query = PredicateBuilder.True<StructureAnalysis>();
query = query.And(analysis =>
        // The names match
        analysis.Name == structureAnalysis.Name &&
        // We have the same # of goals so they must all match.
        analysis.Goals.Count == structureAnalysis.Goals.Count
    );
predicate = predicate.And(t => query.Invoke(t.StructureAnalysis));
```

This will work fine:

```
StructureAnalyses.AsExpandable().Where(query).Dump();
```

...assuming `StructureAnalyses` is an `IQueryable` of my `StructureAnalysis` objects from Entity Framework.

But let's say I want to get the Tasks, filtering with the related StructureAnalyses. **How can I do such a thing?** Keep in mind that in reality, `query` is built out by a reusable function, and `predicate` is built out in a separate function that calls it, so I can't simply merge the two queries.

It compiles but fails when I try and execute the query:

```
Tasks.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).Dump();
```

...with *"The parameter 't' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression."*, or the like. In this example, `Tasks` is an IQueryable that contains all of the `Task` type entities in my DB.

I've also tried altering this line:

```
        predicate = predicate.And(t => query.Invoke(t.StructureAnalysis));
```

...to:

```
        compiled = query.Compile();
        predicate = predicate.And(t => compiled(t.StructureAnalysis));
```

That also compiles but fails with, *"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'."* and understandably so.

I've also tried calling `Expand` on both `query` and `compiled`, which had no effect, as well as the following "solutions":

- This one seems incomplete (`Utility` is undefined):
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105570/linqkit-the-parameter-was-not-bound-in-the-specified-linq-to-entities-query-e
- This one simply says, "it can't be done" which I refuse to believe:
  [Entity Framework Code First 4.3 / LINQKit predicate for related table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529881/entity-framework-code-first-4-3-linqkit-predicate-for-related-table)

Comment: I think the proposed close reason is invalid.

Comment: @Shoe The code provides doesn't reproduce the problem; the close reason is entirely valid.  Or were you able to reproduce the problem described using the code provided?

Comment: @Servy I updated the Q some time ago and pinged you in the comments to your answer. I'm pretty sure you'll be able to reproduce it now, but let me know if you can't.

Comment: @Grinn The code currently shown does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Servy The code shown is the code in its entirety as executed in LINQPad. No worries though as I've found a solution to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution on my own. The trick is to wrap the invocation of `query` in another predicate that accesses the property, then expand that predicate when calling it. So for my example where I'm attempting to invoke a query on a single `StructureAnalysis`, my code now looks like this:

```
// Note: .Includes removed for brevity's sake.
var task = Tasks.First(t => t.QaConfigTaskId == 2);

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Task>();

// Ensure that the task's own properties match.
predicate = predicate.And(t => t.TaskType == task.TaskType &&
      t.Description == task.Description &&
      t.PreTreatment == task.PreTreatment &&
      t.Treatment == task.Treatment);



var structureAnalysis = task.StructureAnalysis;
var query = PredicateBuilder.True<StructureAnalysis>();
query = query.And(analysis =>
        // The names match
        analysis.Name == structureAnalysis.Name &&
        // We have the same # of goals so they must all match.
        analysis.Goals.Count == structureAnalysis.Goals.Count
    );

//// HERE'S WHAT'S NEW ////

Expression<Func<Task, bool>> subPredicate = t => query.Invoke(t.StructureAnalysis);

predicate = predicate.And(subPredicate.Expand());

Tasks.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).Dump();
```